# Operations on Functions and How it Changes Their Graphs

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

This might sound like a dumb question, but it’s something I’ve been thinking of for a long time. Say you have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. We can graph them and analyse the graphs easily. Now, using only the graphs of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, can you deduce what the graph of $f(x)+g(x)$ might look like? What about $f(x)-g(x)$? What about any other operation that we may perform on the functions (multiplication, division, exponentiation, etc.)?
[1.Here is the graph of $y=x^2$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRncg.jpg)
[2.Here is the graph of $y=e^x$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JCX2.jpg)
[3. Here is the graph of $y=e^x+x^2$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5IHr.jpg)
I simply don’t see how one can get from graph $1$ and graph $2$ to graph “$1+2$”. That’s just an example, though. I’m looking for a more general insight as stated above.

Comment: as @lukic said, if you take the two graphs, stick on coordinates and then add the heights you will get the third graph. That is explicitly what their relationship is. Those graphs aren't geometric objects, if you move them around the coordinate plane while they have the "Same shape" they become totally different functions (and their sums and differences etc become totally different as well) so despite being images of graphs its probably not useful to think of them as geometric objects.

Comment: [1] Suppose for a second we forget about the coordinate plane. On the one hand we have this weird curve mathematicians call a “parabola” and on the other hand we have an equally weird curve referred to as an “exponential curve”. I am interested in seeing how a parabola+an exponential curve equals the curve seen in the third link. Perhaps, it isn’t useful to think of graphs as geometric objects, but there must be some sense in which a parabola+an exponential curve equals the third curve. It seems to me that there must be something fundamental about these curves given that they appear naturally

Comment: [2] when analysing functions. Sure, the coordinate plane is just one convenient way of graphing functions, but even if we were to switch to polar coordinates or a completely different system altogether, my question holds. Is there something fundamentally linking graphical representations of functions, and operations on them?

Comment: My point is that given a parabola and an exponential the shape you end up with by "summing" them could be totally different shapes. Consider your example, $x^2, e^x, e^x + x^2$ and now consider the example $-(x+1)^2, e^x, -(x+1)^2+e^x$ the two resulting shapes are not geometrically similar at all. Yet both start off with a parabola and an exponential. Now you can't produce EVERY possible shape this way so there is some "structure" here of starting with particular shapes and ending with target shapes, but its not geometry, the relationships here have to do with coordinates and functions.

Comment: [1] To drive the point home, an expression like $y = x^2$ looks like $r \frac{sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)^2} $ in the polar coordinate plane. The expression $y = e^x$ similarly looks like $r= \frac{e^{r \cos \theta}}{\sin \theta} $  And the sum $y = x^2 + e^x$  looks like $r = \frac{r^2 \cos \theta + e^{r \cos \theta}}{\sin \theta}$ this is NOT the same as $r = \frac{sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)^2} +  \frac{e^{r \cos \theta}}{\sin \theta}$ so the idea of an "operation" is not even well defined without FIRST picking a coordinate system.

Comment: [2]  So when you ask a question like "Is there something fundamentally linking graphical representations of functions, and operations on them" the answer is not really. There is something fundamental about a choice of "function, coordinate system, and operations on them" but once you drop coordinate system the question becomes a lot hazier. Still, I'm sure there must be some kind deep deep hidden relationship here that be said in a coordinate-free way, but its not going to have anything to do with geometry in the sense you and I understand.

Comment: actually i think we can go deeper than this, it is worthwhile to ask the question, is possible for ANY graph $G$ to be produced by  directly "summing" $x^2, e^x$ in the right choice of coordinate system? I think that might actually be true, or at least worth exploring.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal thanks a ton for your insight. I agree that there is some deep hidden relationship here because surely, the curves or graphs or shapes or whatever you want to call them aren’t arbitrary, and are entirely dependent on the starting functions. Perhaps analysing operations on functions, and their graphical representations in different coordinate systems might provide some insight. It’s just that my mathematical lizard brain would be so satisfied to find that there is a context in which one curve “plus” the other equals another, even in a coordinate free world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this might be an interesting problem to consider.

Is true that for any graph of your choice of the form $G(x,y)=0$

There exists a coordinate system $u,v$ such that the sum of $x^2$ and $e^x$ in this coordinate system equals that graph?

What would this entail to prove? We want some functions  $X,Y$ such that

$$ x = X(u,v)\\ y = Y(u, v)$$

So then we can rewrite

$$ y = x^2 \rightarrow Y(u,v) = X(u,v)^2$$
$$ y = e^x \rightarrow Y(u,v) = e^{X(u,v)}$$

And we should be able to rewrite these equations as

$$ u = F_1(v) $$
$$ u = F_2(v) $$

Such that the graph

$$ u = F_1(v) + F_2(v)$$

Should be identical to the graph $G(x,y) = 0$.

This would be a pretty tricky theorem to prove but personally my hunch is that it is always possible regardless of the choice of $G$.

Comment: Woah stuff just got taken to the next level. This stuff is definitely picking at my brain and I’m going to give it some more thought.

Answer (score 0):

As I am not yet able to write comments, please excuse that I use an answer for what should be a comment.

What you can always do is, of course, plot both graphs and then "add" the height of one graph onto the other one, but I'd consider it cheating in this case.

Generally, what you are asking for is tricky. You might want to try to do that for two linear maps f(x)=ax and g(x)=bx first. Even then, you will notice that it is not trivial to figure out the slope of f(x)+g(x) = (a+b)x without some arithmetics. Naively, one might assume that it suffices to plot f, and then rotate according to the slope of g. But already for the case of f(x)=x=g(x), such a strategy would leave you with something that is not a function.

It is a really interesting question, nonetheless, and someone else might have some more tricks up their sleeves.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Of course, you can “add”, or “subtract”, or perform whatever operation on the height of the graph, but like you said it’s kinda boring. I was wondering if the new curves formed would have interesting mathematical properties that we could deduce using the initial curves or something along those lines. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you ever heard of commutative algebra or algebraic geometry? The graphs of any polynomials are (affine) varieties, and there is a hell of a lot of theory on the interaction of varieties under various operations. You might be interested in diving into that field a bit.

Comment: Yes, I’ve heard of that stuff, but I’ve barely looked into it. This stuff sounds abstract and pure enough for me to be interested in it so I guess I know what I’m going to be watching on YouTube while eating.